# Add driver to Windows 2003 install

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have one DELL PowerEdge T105 , this server works with a RAID SAS this driver is not on Windows CD, normally these drivers add with  a diskette in the installation by pressing F3 , iss posible to add the driver to one directory in the windows server 20003 CD??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/guide/), which allows you to customize Windows installs. Basically, it takes a Windows install CD and allows you to customize it (integrate drivers, add service packs, etc).  The end result is an ISO file which you will have to burn to CD.

It has been a while but I used it to add a RAID driver to my Windows XP install.